# Importing Tkinter and rowspan/sticky question

Tags: python, tkinter, sticky

I am writing a program to generate draft emails, and I am trying to set it up with a tkinter GUI. I'm on Python 3.5 with tkinter 8.6.

My issue is that I cannot get rowspan to work. I want to have the first row span a few rows, but when I add 'rowspan' the row doesn't change size. If I add 'sticky=tK.N+tK.S', I get errors that those mean nothing. So then I started messing with how I was importing tkinter, trying it as importing from, importing as tk, importing *, but everything I change breaks soemthing else, and still doesn't get the north-south stickiness that I am looking for so that the row will stretch out and fill the space.

I am pretty sure that this is an issue with how I am importing tkinter, and any advice would be tremendously appreciated. I also can't get tkinter to work if I use 'import tkinter as tk" because then I get errors like name 'StringVar' is not defined". I tried fixing that by moving where my root was declared, but that created issues with GUI.

Help! Thanks :)

```
import os
# pull in GUI stuff
import tkinter as tk #import Tk, Label, Button, W, E, N, S, StringVar, OptionMenu, Entry, Text, END, WORD
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

path = os.getcwd()


# init GUI
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Email Draft Builder")
        # set logo image
        f = os.getcwd() + "\\cgs_logo.gif"
        # lock in image for use outside this section
        im = Image.open(f)
        ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        # vars to show dynamic text for displays 1 and 2
        self.box1_titleText = tk.StringVar()
        self.box2_titleText = tk.StringVar()

        self.box1_content = tk.StringVar()
        self.box2_content = tk.StringVar()

# main/container pane info
        self.label = tk.Label(master, text="Email Draft Composer", image = ph, bg = "#ffffff")
        self.label.image = ph
        self.label.grid(columnspan = 3, row = 0, rowspan = 2, sticky=tk.N+
                        tk.S, column=1)

# ROW 1
        self.readLast_button = tk.Button(master, text="Read Training File", command=self.dataOps)
        self.readLast_button.grid(row=3, column=0,sticky=tk.W)

# ROW 2
        self.file_button = tk.Button(master, text="Unused", command=self.chooseSite)
        self.file_button.grid(row=4, column=0,sticky=tk.W)

# ROW 3
        self.pullSite_button = tk.Button(master, text="Show Site Info:", command=self.pullSite)
        self.pullSite_button.grid(row=5, column=0,sticky=tk.W)

        self.getSite = tk.Entry(master)
        self.getSite.grid(row=5, column=1,sticky=tk.W)

# ROW 4
        self.sendEmail_button = tk.Button(master, text="Build Email", command=self.sendEmail)
        self.sendEmail_button.grid(row=6, column=0,sticky=tk.W)

        recipients = ["mgancsos@cogstate.com","mgancsos@gmail.com","kkiernan@cogstate.com;mchabon@cogstate.com","ashortland@cogstate.com"]
        self.receiver = tk.StringVar()
        self.receiver.set(recipients[0])
        self.menu1 = tk.OptionMenu(master, self.receiver, *recipients)
        self.menu1.grid(row=6, column=1,sticky=tk.W)

# ROW 5
        self.close_button = tk.Button(master, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
        self.close_button.grid(row=7, column=0,sticky=tk.W)

# ROW 6
        self.box1_title = tk.Label(master, textvariable=self.box1_titleText, bg = "#fffff0", borderwidth=1, relief = "groove", width = 15)
        self.box1_title.grid(columnspan=1, row = 8, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        self.box1_pane = tk.Label(master, textvariable=self.box1_content, bg = "#fffff0", borderwidth=1, relief = "groove", width = 55)
        self.box1_pane.grid(columnspan=1, row = 8, column=1,  sticky=tk.W)

# ROW 7
        self.box2_title = tk.Label(master, textvariable=self.box2_titleText, bg = "#ffff00", borderwidth=1, relief = "groove", width = 15)
        self.box2_title.grid(columnspan=1, row = 9, column=0, sticky='nw')
        self.box2_pane = tk.Label(master, textvariable=self.box2_content, bg = "#ffffff", borderwidth=1, relief = "groove", width = 55)
        self.box2_pane.grid(columnspan=1, row = 9, column=1, sticky='NW')
# ROW 8
        self.display1 = tk.Text(master, wrap=tk.WORD)
        self.display1.grid(columnspan=1, row = 10, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

    def dataOps(self):
        return(1)

    def chooseSite(self):
        return(1)        

    def pullSite(self):
        return(1)        

    def sendEmail(self):
        return(1)        


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x800')
root["bg"] = "#ffffff"
my_gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you do `import tkinter as tk`, then you have to prefix every Tkinter object with `tk.`: `tk.StringVar()`, `tk.Button()`, etc.  As for your main question, `rowspan=` has no visible effect unless there are other widgets in the rows being spanned.

Comment: Also if you are using sticky= then the syntax is sticky=(tk.N, tk.S) I believe

Comment: You've posted a whole bunch of code that seems unrelated to the problem. Please try to condense the code down to a [mcve] designed specifically for this question.

Comment: @Ben, using that gets me "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument". I've read elsewhere that using sticky to stretch to fill has to be "+".

Comment: Edited down the code.

Comment: @jasonharper, thank you! I fixed the import. I don't know why the "import *" bombs on me, but I'd rather add tk. to everything than not get this to work. How does not having a widget in the row factor into this? I have a label in that row: self.label.